# Showing detail view when cell tapped Swift Parse

Tags: ios, swift, segue

So as the title says I'm trying to show a detail view when a cell is tapped. My issue is with the prepareForSegue function I'm using. I don't get any errors but when I run on the simulator I get an uncaught exception. It occurs on the last line of the prepareForSegue function. Its finding nil for the names and I'm not sure why the variable is nil. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: The uncaught error is no longer a problem. Now the data is not being displayed when the cell is tapped.

```
class LocalPostsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

var currentIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

var names = [String]()
var locations = [String]()
var dates = [String]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
var abouts = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint, error) -> Void in
        if let geoPoint = geoPoint {
            PFUser.currentUser()?["location"] = geoPoint
            PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()

    var getLocalPostsQuery = PFQuery(className: "publicPosts")
    if let latitude = PFUser.currentUser()!["location"].latitude {
        if let longitude = PFUser.currentUser()!["location"].longitude {
    getLocalPostsQuery.whereKey("searchLocation", withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest: PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude - 0.5, longitude: longitude - 0.5), toNortheast:  PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude + 0.5, longitude: longitude + 0.5))
    getLocalPostsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {

                self.names.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.locations.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.abouts.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.dates.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for object in objects {

                    self.names.append(object["name"] as! String)
                    self.locations.append(object["location"] as! String)
                    self.dates.append(object["date"] as! String)
                    self.abouts.append(object["about"] as! String)
                    self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return names.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let LECell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LocalPostsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LocalPostsTableViewCell

    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            LECell.postImage.image = downloadedImage
        }
    }


    LECell.postName.text = names[indexPath.row]
    LECell.postLocation.text = locations[indexPath.row]
    LECell.postDate.text = dates[indexPath.row]

    return LECell
}

let localPostsDetailSegue = "showLocalPostsDetailView"

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == localPostsDetailSegue {
        let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! LocalPostsDetailViewController

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            detailScene.postName?.text = names[row]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just pass string to next controller and set this text to label in `viewDidLoad` of next screen.

Define:

```
var postName: String!
```

in `LocalPostsDetailViewController`

and in `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == localPostsDetailSegue {
    let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! LocalPostsDetailViewController

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        detailScene.postName = names[row]
    }
}
```

}

In `viewDidLoad` of `LocalPostsDetailViewController` set it:

```
self.postName?.text = postName
```

Comment: tried that but when i do detailScene.postName?.text = postName
it says detailScene is an unresolved identifier

Comment: sorry I put name is `postname` not `postName` so it error. Please change it and try again.

Comment: ah change it `detailScene.postName?.text = postName` to `self.postName?.text = postName`

Comment: Error is gone but nothing is displayed on the next view... do i maybe need to reload the data?

Comment: can you check `postName` data? Is it passed?

Comment: where should i check it in the tableviewcontroller or detailviewcontroler?

Comment: in `detailViewController`.

Comment: the data is not being passed

Comment: Ok. Now you check data in `prepareSegue`: check `names[row]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97462/discussion-between-vien-vu-and-m1234).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need on using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Just define the segue in the storyBoard with the identifier and the following should work:

```
let localPostsDetailSegue = "showLocalPostsDetailView"  

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == localPostsDetailSegue {
            let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! LocalPostsDetailViewController

            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let row = Int(indexPath.row)
                detailScene.postName?.text = names[row]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I updated my code to your answer and I'm still getting the error that Its finding nil when unwrapping an optional value on: detailScene.postName.text! = names[row]

Comment: does the tableView loads with the right data? Does the error occurs only when you tap the cell?

Comment: The error occurs when I tap the cell and it causes a crash

Comment: just made an edit. try `detailScene.postName?.text = names[row]`

Comment: Awesome! That fixed the crash! But now the label isn't being updated

Comment: so actually you dont have any information on names for the row you are selecting. Could you please edit the question with the whole class?

Comment: Updated question with full class